# System.ArgumentException: In a route parameter, '{' and '}' must be escaped with '{{' and '}}'. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')

Tags: api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm porting an old API project to .NET Core 3.1 API project. All endpoints in old are working fine. While testing the new API on local IIS 10/Windows 10 I'm getting this error:

> System.ArgumentException: In a route parameter, '{' and '}' must be
> escaped with '{{' and '}}'. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')

The specific route in question is not shown in the error. So I am including all routes here.

1. `[Route("department/{id:int}")]`
2. `[Route("program/{deptId:int}")]`
3. `[Route(@"employee/{samId:regex(^[[A-Za-z0-9._-]]{3,30}$)}")]`
4. `[Route(@"homepage/{samId:regex(^[[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]]{3,30}$)}")]`

On #2 and #3 I have double `[` and double `]` because I was getting error on those as well earlier when they were single.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message

```
System.ArgumentException: In a route parameter, '{' and '}' must be escaped with '{{' and '}}'. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')
```

you need to add one more `{}` in front, like this：

```
 [Route(@"test/{{samId:regex(^[[A-Za-z0-9._-]]{3,30}$)}}")]
```

Comment: It was actually the inner `{}` representing the length constraints that needed the escape character. Not the outer `{}`: `[Route(@"test/{samId:regex(^[[A-Za-z0-9._-]]{{3,30}}$)}")]`. 

This must've been a change in .NET Core 3.1 because same route template has been working for me in ASP.NET Web API 2

Comment: I am using the .NET Core 3.1 version. I used your code at the beginning and reproduced your error. Later, I changed it according to the prompts and everything was normal.